# How to spy on a method in class property?

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

class App extends Component {
    a = {
        func: () => 1
    };

    render () {
        return null;
    }
}

describe('<App>', () => {
    test('func()', () => {
        const app = shallow(<App />),
              func_spy = jest.spyOn(???);
    });
});
```

I want to spy on `func` function at `a` class property. Can I achieve it using `spyOn` method or something? Thank you in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the class instance using [`.instance`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/instance.html) and use it to create the spy:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

class App extends Component {
  a = {
    func: () => 1
  };

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

describe('<App>', () => {
  test('func()', () => {
    const app = shallow(<App />);
    const instance = app.instance();  // <= get the instance
    const func_spy = jest.spyOn(instance.a, 'func');  // <= spy on instance.a.func

    instance.a.func();

    expect(func_spy).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
  });
});
```